# C/C++, NTFS. Multiple reparse points

Tags: c++, c, winapi, ntfs, reparsepoint

MSDN says "There is a limit of 31 reparse points on any given path."
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
So, a single file can have max. 31 reparse points (?)

To check if a file has "a" reparse point, GetFileAttributes can be used
(mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
and to get the content of "the" reparse point DeviceIoControl with FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT is needed (cant post a third link because of low reputation)

But i see no possibility to specify what reparse data i want if there are multiple?
GetFileAttributes will say only Yes/No instead of a count or something like that,
and DeviceIoControl will fill one single REPARSE_GUID_DATA_BUFFER structure (according to MSDN), without any possibilty to give a GUID or index or somtehing like that.

edit: My question if i´ve understood this with 31 reparse points right and how i can access them.

Comment: I see a question mark but no actual question.

Comment: I think the important part of the docs is `any given` *`path`*, i.e. the cumulative count of reparse points between all segments of a given path. That may technically exceed `31` in completely *<strike>out of control</strike>* over-engineered structures, and a file would still technically only match a single combination of of reparse points.

Comment: @ Captain Obvlious: Added a specific question above.                  @Frédéric Hamidi: But a directory containing a reparse point itself cannot have any content (ie. files in it). Or do you mean, if i take junction points or something like that as example, that the system can only proces 31 reparse points in a single file open call "on the way" to the file? Will test that later...

Comment: `C:\This\Is\A\Complex\Path`. `This` can be a reparse point, as can `Is`, as can `A`, as can `Complex`, etc.. up to a maximum of 31.

Comment: @Jonathan, indeed, and the admin should be taken out and ***XMAS CENSORED***.

Comment: Thanks you all, Frédéric Hamidi and Jonathan Potter are right (of course ;)
(@Frédéric Hamidi: If i´ve done something wrong, please say so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood the MSDN docs wrong:
A file/directory itself can have only one reparse point itself
(and a directory can have more than 31 files/directories with reparse points in it, of course)

The limit 31 is only valid for nested symlinks (etc.), ie.
Case 1:
Link1->Link2, Link2->Link3, ... Link32->RealDir
Here it would not be possible to open Link1 if i want RealDir
Case 2:
If i want to open C:\L1\L2\L3\L4...\L32\file.txt
and L1 is a symlink to another directory,
the target´s subdirectory L2 is another symlink, and so on,
this too wouldn´t be possible with >31 nested links.